# Nginx & PHP FPM 502 Bad Gateway (Resource temporarily unavailable)

Tags: php, linux, nginx

I have no idea my server twice a day get 502 bad gateway. I have made lots of tweaks but none of them are working. Here is my dedicated specification

2x E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz [32 cores]
32 GB RAM

Here is PHP FPM log

```
07-Oct-2022 11:53:19] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140615, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/api.php' (request: "POST /api.php?f=enterServer") executing too slow (5.191753 sec), logging
[07-Oct-2022 11:53:19] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140613, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1/api-bot.php' (request: "GET /api-bot.php?f=runTask") executing too slow (5.108451 sec), logging
[07-Oct-2022 11:53:19] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140609, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1/api.php' (request: "POST /api.php?f=registerCitizen") executing too slow (5.151089 sec), logging
[07-Oct-2022 11:53:19] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140606, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1/api-bot.php' (request: "GET /api-bot.php?f=runWork") executing too slow (5.204648 sec), logging
[07-Oct-2022 11:53:19] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140604, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1/api.php' (request: "POST /api.php?f=citizenWork") executing too slow (5.174349 sec), logging
[07-Oct-2022 11:54:21] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140635, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1/api-bot.php' (request: "GET /api-bot.php?f=runWork") executing too slow (5.840929 sec), logging
[07-Oct-2022 11:54:21] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140632, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1/api-bot.php' (request: "GET /api-bot.php?f=runWork") executing too slow (6.222622 sec), logging
[07-Oct-2022 11:54:21] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140627, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1/api.php' (request: "POST /api.php?f=citizenWork") executing too slow (6.403859 sec), logging
[07-Oct-2022 11:55:14] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140613, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1/api-bot.php' (request: "GET /api-bot.php?f=runTask") execution timed out (120.127614 sec), terminating
[07-Oct-2022 11:55:14] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140606, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1/api-bot.php' (request: "GET /api-bot.php?f=runWork") execution timed out (120.223811 sec), terminating
[07-Oct-2022 11:55:14] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140606 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 124.885829 seconds from start
[07-Oct-2022 11:55:14] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140613 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 122.681948 seconds from start
[07-Oct-2022 11:55:21] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140739, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1/api-bot.php' (request: "GET /api-bot.php?f=runWork") executing too slow (5.820752 sec), logging
[07-Oct-2022 11:55:21] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140737, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1/api-bot.php' (request: "GET /api-bot.php?f=runWork") executing too slow (6.638456 sec), logging
[07-Oct-2022 11:55:21] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140736, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1/api-bot.php' (request: "GET /api-bot.php?f=runTask") executing too slow (6.573738 sec), logging
[07-Oct-2022 11:56:16] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140632, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1/api-bot.php' (request: "GET /api-bot.php?f=runWork") execution timed out (121.254372 sec), terminating
[07-Oct-2022 11:56:16] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140632 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 121.322812 seconds from start
[07-Oct-2022 11:56:21] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140635, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1/api-bot.php' (request: "GET /api-bot.php?f=runWork") executing too slow (6.181178 sec), logging
[07-Oct-2022 11:56:23] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140747, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1/api-bot.php' (request: "GET /api-bot.php?f=runTask") executing too slow (6.635953 sec), logging
[07-Oct-2022 11:57:16] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140739, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1/api-bot.php' (request: "GET /api-bot.php?f=runWork") execution timed out (120.846432 sec), terminating
[07-Oct-2022 11:57:16] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140737, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1/api-bot.php' (request: "GET /api-bot.php?f=runWork") execution timed out (121.664136 sec), terminating
[07-Oct-2022 11:57:16] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140737 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 121.690783 seconds from start
[07-Oct-2022 11:57:16] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140739 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 120.927065 seconds from start
[07-Oct-2022 11:57:21] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140736, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1/api-bot.php' (request: "GET /api-bot.php?f=runWork") executing too slow (5.359786 sec), logging
[07-Oct-2022 11:57:23] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140758, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1/api-bot.php' (request: "GET /api-bot.php?f=runWork") executing too slow (6.440587 sec), logging
[07-Oct-2022 11:57:23] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140757, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1/api-bot.php' (request: "GET /api-bot.php?f=runTask") executing too slow (6.529727 sec), logging
[07-Oct-2022 11:58:16] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140635, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1/api-bot.php' (request: "GET /api-bot.php?f=runWork") execution timed out (121.203518 sec), terminating
[07-Oct-2022 11:58:16] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140635 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 241.053774 seconds from start
[07-Oct-2022 11:58:23] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140766, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1/api-bot.php' (request: "GET /api-bot.php?f=runWork") executing too slow (6.561763 sec), logging
[07-Oct-2022 11:58:23] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140747, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1/api-bot.php' (request: "GET /api-bot.php?f=runWork") executing too slow (6.515532 sec), logging
[07-Oct-2022 11:59:14] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140831, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1/api-bot.php' (request: "GET /api-bot.php?f=runTask") executing too slow (5.697952 sec), logging
[07-Oct-2022 11:59:16] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140736, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1/api-bot.php' (request: "GET /api-bot.php?f=runWork") execution timed out (120.390085 sec), terminating
[07-Oct-2022 11:59:18] WARNING: [pool dsimlife-user] child 140758, script '/home/dsimlife/public_html/id1/api-bot.php' (request: "GET /api-bot.php?f=runWork") execution timed out (121.471340 sec), terminating
```

Here is my nginx configuration

```
user  nobody;
worker_processes 1;
worker_rlimit_nofile 2500;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

pid     /var/run/nginx.pid;
include /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc/modsecurity*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

error_log /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/error_log debug;


http {
    include    mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/web.access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush  on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_requests 200;
    keepalive_timeout  130;

    #gzip  on;
    
    client_max_body_size 200M;
    
    # If your domain names are long, increase this parameter.
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    
    # To hide the version number in headers
    server_tokens off;
    
    include /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Here is my PHP-FPM conf

```
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 0
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_requests = 20
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10
request_terminate_timeout = 120s
```

Can anyone tell me what should configuration would be. The main problem is, the server sometime lead to 502 bad gateway where the resource is still fine.

Comment: Isn't there any related line in error.log?

Comment: connect() to unix:/usr/local/apps/php74/var/fpm-dsimlife.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)

Comment: And is there any related in syslog? Or messages? Do you have any monitoring system? (I mean do you have any information about requests/sec in these times?)

Comment: adding php-fpm log

Comment: Thanks, you should take a look this: https://serverfault.com/a/520895/172797